# best data structure to store a telephone directory when it has to be accessed via both name and number

Tags: java, c, algorithm, data-structures

was wondering what would be the best data structure to store a telephone directory when it has to be accessed via both name and number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data Structure for phone book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107438/data-structure-for-phone-book)

Comment: When measuring performance, a linear search over an array may turn out to be among the fastest options due to the way we currently build our machines. Start with the most naive implementation and begin optimizing when necessary.

Comment: Tough to call that a duplicate when the answers are poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in c++ you can have a look to boost::bimap (Bidirectionnal map) on this web page : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

If you create a boost::bimap to store your directory all will be fine.

I think you can find an implementation of BiMap in Java.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

There is a bimap:  http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html

Answer (score 1):

As @Anycorn mentioned you can have a look into BidiMap or you can do the same with Google Guava BiMap, tutorial here: http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/10/guavas-bidirectional-maps.html